# What does this notation do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for the bad title, but I couldn't come up with something better.

I found the following line of code in a legacy project I have to maintain. However, I have ABSOLUTELY no idea what this does or how it works.

```
$('.js-legend-input')[operation]('chapter__inputs--hidden');
```

The variable `operation` is defined as the following:

```
const operation = active === 'chapter' ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass';
```

I can only suspect that this line executes the function `addClass` and `removeClass` on the `.js-legend-input` and works with the parameters in the parentheses. So is this notation just a "shorthand" for:

```
if(active === 'chapter') {
    $('.js-legend-input').addClass('chapter__inputs--hidden');
} else {
    $('.js-legend-input').removeClass('chapter__inputs--hidden');
}
```

Because I know sure as hell I have never seen that before.

Comment: `[operation === 'active' ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']` is just dynamically calling a property of `$('.js-legend-input')`. This is another way of [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct, that's what it does.

Comment: Remember `$('.js-legend-input')` return an object and you can acces like array with bracket notation

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does. If your key is stored in a variable, you have to use bracket notation to use it. And putting `(...)` behind anything that evaluates to a function will call it.

Comment: Prime example of a past developer attempting to be clever, and making the code less readable for future developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely correct. It's exactly what it does, plus:

- If parameter values change, then you only need to update that one line in legacy code, instead of two in case of the **if**s

  ```
  $('.js-legend-input')[ operation ]( 'chapter__inputs--hidden' ) ;
  ```
- If a new operation is possible, like for example `toggleClass` then you don't have to add another **if**, you can just call it with variable `operation = 'toggleClass'` . Neat, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for confirming my theory! It's actually pretty neat, but I could have needed a comment on that because I had no idea what that is. xD

Comment: It is neat if new operations are added. JS is the wild wild west, you can do a lot with it, it's one of my favorite programming languages. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you are right, this notation **[operation]** is called **bracket notation** and it is used to access object properties along with the **dot notation** (just having . followed by the property name). The bracket notation allows the usage of variables as property names this is why it is used in this scenario. The variable **`operation`** just replaces the name of the property with its value.